# Group Join Vs Include Vs Projection queries, what is the difference?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, include, projection

To the best of my knowledges, Group Join vs. Include vs. Projection queries all bring nested entities or should I say hierarchical data - usually for one to many. Also, they all render as a join on the DB level - either Inner or Left depending on Foreign key set up. I guess EF is making them nested from flat.

With projection queries we can precisely select the columns we need both for the outer and inner level of the nested entities. With Include we can not select specific columns, as far as I know. I am not sure how it goes for the Group Join ?.

Am I correct and what else you can say ?? Thank you.

I researched but did not find even questions asked in this matter.